# Google Analytics Regex Search Replace String with Exclusion

Tags: regex, search, replace, google-analytics

We're having an issue accurately tracking enrollment goal conversion by device category since we several hundred SEM and ad tag tracking codes. So I'm trying to develop a **regex search** and replace string in Google Analytics that takes all enrollment/semcode and enrollment?adtag links and combine them into enrollment/ with the one exception of enrollment/thank-you.

I've ran across several examples, but since Goggle Analytics doesn't support negative lookaheads or lookbehinds I'm having trouble coming up with a solution. Some suggestions as follows:

```
^/(?!thank-you)[enrollment.*?]
^/(?!thank-you)([enrollment.*?]+)$
```

One interesting one I got was this:

```
/enrollment((\/[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}((\?|\/).*)?)|(\?motherhood-state=.*)|(\?param=from_pop_up.*))?$
```

But I don't think it will capture all the links.

Example link structure.

```
enrollment/
enrollment/thank-you
enrollment/semcode
enrollment?someparam
user?destination=enrollment/semcode
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Does anything need to be captured? Does anything else start with `t`? (The regex `^.*?enrollment[/?]([a-su-z].*)?$` might work then.)

Comment: As far as I know, nothing else starts with t. I want to capture all the enrollment links except for the thank you page. Then I'll use GA to replace them with the link I want. In this case everything would be /enrollment.

Comment: BTW I figured out the regex engine supports inverted character classes: `^.*?enrollment[/?]([^t].*)?$` is a better version of the previous regex.

Comment: That's actually good to know and I'm testing this out now.